# Finding word frequencies

Tags: javascript

I'm completely new to JavaScript and having issue with figuring out how to make a word counter. I'm trying to create a list of key/value pairs for an associative array based off of each word in the sentence, split by spaces. The key would be the word and the value would be the tally of each word in the sentence. For example, a sentence of "The man walked to the store" is supposed to have an output like:

The 2

man 1

walked 1

to 1

store 1

However when I go to console.log the array it prints out something like:

Undefined: (Random number)

Would this be because the key/value pairs aren't actually being defined, or is the code only defining it once then adding it all to the one pair? This is making me feel quite dumb if I'm gonna be honest. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. My code is below:

```js
function calcWordFrequencies(userInput) {
    var asscArray = {};
    //var userInput = prompt("Enter a sentence and the program will make a tally of each word.");
    
    userInput.split(" ");
    
    for (var items of userInput) {
        if (userInput[items] in asscArray) {
            asscArray[userInput[items]] += 1;
        }
        else {
            asscArray[userInput[items]] = 1;
        }
    }
    for (var item in asscArray) {
        console.log(item + ": " + asscArray[item] + "\n");
    }   
}

calcWordFrequencies("The man walked to the store");
```

Comment: You need `userInput = userInput.split(" ");`

Comment: DEBUG! Learn to debug! `for (var items of userInput) {
        console.log(items, userInput[items])`

Comment: A for of loop doesn't use the index but the actual array element: https://jsfiddle.net/mjhdkztn/

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to assign `userInput` to the returned value of `split`
2. the loop should be `for in` for `userInput`
3. use `toLowerCase` to ignore case

```js
function calcWordFrequencies(userInput) {
    var asscArray = {};
    // var userInput = prompt("Enter a sentence and the program will make a tally of each word.");

    userInput = userInput.split(" ");

    for (var items in userInput) {
        var char = userInput[items].toLowerCase();
        if (char in asscArray) {
            asscArray[char] += 1;
        }
        else {
            asscArray[char] = 1;
        }
    }
    for (var item in asscArray) {
        console.log(item + ": " + asscArray[item] + "\n");
    }   
}

calcWordFrequencies("The man walked to the store");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve this

```
const sentence = "The man walked to the store";

// use split to convert sentence into an array, split by a space
const wordCounter = sentence.split(' ').reduce((accum, word) => {
  if (!accum[word]) {  // if a property of the word doesn't currently exist, create it and set value to 1
    accum[word] = 1;
  } else {  // if a property of the word does exist, increment the current value
    accum[word]++;
  }

  return accum;
}, {}) // the accum starts of as an empty object
```

The result of console logging wordCounter would be:

```
{
  The: 1
  man: 1
  store: 1
  the: 1
  to: 1
  walked: 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Map` that maps each word to its count:

```js
let res = "something something somethingelse somethingelse something"
               .split(" ")
               .reduce(
                    (a, el) => (a.set(el, (a.get(el) + 1 || 1)), a),
                     new Map
               );
// just for output purpose
console.log([...res])
```

However `Map` can be slower than using a normal object (but they can handle more informations), you might want to use a simple object:

```js
let res = "something something somethingelse somethingelse something".split(" ").reduce((a, el) => (a[el] =a[el] + 1 || 1, a), {});
console.log(res);
```